# Registering an MSBuild custom logger to Visual Studio

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I created a custom logger by extending the Logger class and I was able to attach this logger to msbuild on the command line. I did it in the following manner:

`msbuild Sample.proj /l:CustomLogger,MSBuildCustomLogger.dll`

And it was working properly, but I wanted to extend this to Visual Studio also. So I was looking for a way to attach this custom logger when building the solution / project inside Visual Studio. I have been looking through different resources to do this but I couldn't find any way to extend the logging mechanism of Visual Studio until now. Is there any way to implement this? I would appreciate any help / hints regarding this issue.

Comment: I thought this has been asked before but cannot find any duplicate - anyway I'm pretty sure the answer was that it cannot be done. VS invokes MsBuild programatically and does not seem to provide any extensions points for it. Which is a pitty.

Comment: Note I just posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28806181/128384 which sort of applies for you as well. It's a rather ugly hack though and i would not recommend it for production unless tested properly.